# Error when trying to test a mathematical proof

Tags: java

So I'm creating a short test just to see if my friend's proof is rightt being that there are no positive integers that, when written twice (i.e. 10->1010) is a perfect square.

```
package checker;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         for(int i=10001; i<1000000; i++) {
            String repeat = i + "" + i;
            int x = Integer.valueOf(repeat);
            double root = Math.sqrt(x);

            if (root == Math.floor(root) && !Double.isInfinite(root)) {
                System.out.println("When " + i + " is repeated and the root is taken of it, the result, " + x
                + " IS a perfect square.");
            }
         }
    }
};
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2147521475"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
at checker.Checker.main(Checker.java:11)
```

I'm fairly new to Java so I do not understand a whole lot. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is out of range of interger. Integer max value is 2147483647

Answer (score 0):

The largest value that can be represented by an `int` in Java is 2,147,483,647. The value you are trying to parse (2,147,521,475) is too large to be represented as an `int`.

The `NumberFormatException` is Java's way of saying that the string "2147521475" cannot be parsed as an integer.

If you use a `long` rather than an `int` (i.e. change `int x = Integer.valueOf` to `long x = Long.valueOf`) then you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of an `int` is 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or 2147483647. Your number, 2147521475, exceeds this value (and is the first such number your program will try).

As a temporary stop-gap, you can use `long`, whose maximum value is 2<sup>63</sup>-1, using `long x = Long.valueOf(repeat)`.

However, this will still eventually break (although after a long time depending on the computer used and the algorithm). You can use `BigInteger` for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. 
Minimum value is - 2,147,483,648.(-2^31) 
Maximum value is 2,147,483,647(inclusive).(2^31 -1)

Use `long`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for(long i=10001; i<1000000; i++) {
        String repeat = i + "" + i;
        long x = Long.valueOf(repeat);
        double root = Math.sqrt(x);

        if (root == Math.floor(root) && !Double.isInfinite(root)) {
            System.out.println("When " + i + " is repeated and the root is taken of it, the result, " + x
            + " IS a perfect square.");
        }
     }
}
```